# javascript: как работать с предупреждениями типа "Expected '===' and instead saw '==' eqeqeq"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jslint

Подскажите как можно управлять предупреждениями типа

> Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq

В сети написано, что это предупреждения от `JSLint` и можно указать нужные характеристики в файле `jshintrc`

У меня проект на React, использую Visual Studio. Никакого `jshintrc` найти не могу. Т.е. надо предварительно установить `JSLint`? Просто у меня сложилось впечатление, что раз вылезают такие предупреждения, то уже всё, что надо установлено.

Comment: А почему бы не заменить в проекте == на === ?

Comment: я так и делал, но у меня эстетические чувства начинают страдать, когда приходится писать

`a === null || a === undefined`

Comment: Ну так для js == и === это разное! 1 == '1' -> true  1 === '1' -> false

Comment: в том то и дело, поэтому я не могу использовать `!a`, потому что там может быть 0

Comment: JSHint древность. Скорее всего у вас всё-таки `eslint`. Настраивайте https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/eqeqeq#smart

Comment: Попробуйте найти в VS настройку JSHint и отключить там опцию eqeqeq

Comment: Добавлю что для сравнения с undefined и null есть оператор `??`

Comment: @sailybra, на счет `??` как вы его примените к следующему коду `res = data == undefined ? [1, 10, 100] : data.map(x => 2 * x)`

Comment: @Zhihar, `res = data?.map(x => 2 * x) ?? [1, 10, 100]`

Answer (score 1):

Если установка производилась через `npm create-react-app` то тогда ничего дополнительно устанавливать не нужно. Все настроенные пакеты находятся в папке `node_modules/react-scripts`. В ней и хранятся "почти" все настройки.